# How much to tip for a free meal in Mexico?

Tags: hotels, mexico, tipping

The hotels in the area when I am staying often offer breakfast included with the room. At the end of the meal, they usually drop off a tray with candies which also says 'Tips' or 'Propina' (Spanish for tips).

Do most people leave tips? If so how much more or less?

Comment: I have never seen this in Mexico, but I would probably leave 5-10 pesos if I was dining alone, and maybe 5 per person for more, and not any more.

Comment: @Flimzy - Yes. This is my 6th time in Mexico and the first time I encountered it. Maybe its a Puebla thing :)

Comment: I've been to Puebla 3 times, and never experienced it there, either... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When it comes to tipping there are no generic rules. There are recommendations which may or may not be followed. When it comes to complimentary breakfasts or complimentary meals I usually apply a monetary value to them and tip according to that.

What most people do is in this case irrelevant because it's your money and your expectation of service if you are staying multiple days in the same hotel. So if you're unable to see what people are leaving for tips you should consider how much this meal is worth to you and leave the tips according to that.

Answer (score -1):

In strict Mexican law terms, tip is optional. Far from law terms in ordinary day people generally leaves 10% tip of check balance in any restaurant if you are happy with the service. In luxury places, maybe you could leave 15 even 20%.

Comment: The question was how much is 10% (or whatever percentage) of zero? Sorry but this does not add anything to answer the situation.

Comment: Haha agree. I omitted read the "free" word. Correcting: depends of place. Any nice hotel about from 60 to 80 MXN (between 3 to 4 US dollars) could be enough. Any standard hotel, 30 - 40 MXN (1.5 to 2 US dollar)